# How would I query AircraftData[] by the type property?

Tags: entity

This is probably a very basic question.

I would like to pull a list of `Aircraft` from `AircraftData[]` where the `Type` property is equal to a specified value.

I tried the following:

```
acData = 
  Select[AircraftData[], AircraftData[#, "Type"] == "interceptor"];
```

This did not work.

I am going through the following entry in the Wolfram Community:

[Search an entity list?](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1902474)

- I was a bit thrown by the use of PostFix `//` on lists in the Wolfram Community article. I am guessing that the `//` is similar to a Linux pipe. It is not described in the documentation.
- Do I need to create a `FilteredEntityClass` from `AircraftData`?
- Are there any references or courses that cover SQL-like queries against entities in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This quite easy. You can use, in principle, but should try to avoid core-functionality searchers like `Select` or `Cases` when you can rely on Entity framework built-in syntax. You can see similar logic in [this doc page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityClass.html).

```
EntityList[Entity["Aircraft", "Type" -> "interceptor"]]
```

[image]

Check:

```
In[]:= Counts[EntityValue[%,"Type"]]
Out[]= <|interceptor->34|>
```

Comment: I need a course on the `Entity...` functions. The document page in your solution is useful. I see the note at the top of the `AircraftData[]` page to use `Aircraft`. I would like to do SQL-like functions such as selecting the unique "Types" in `AircraftData[]`. I have been working with the Wolfram Engine. It may be easier to handle this type of manipulation with LINQ and C#.

Comment: There is a bunch of videos online, like this https://youtu.be/jtSqDOoMHzw or this https://youtu.be/ESRyJskVru8 but there is more. There are SQL thinkers, like https://community.wolfram.com/web/damcalrom you can connect with him on Wolfram Community